# Cup product and suspension

Tags: algebraic-topology

Let $X$ be a topological space with suspension $\Sigma X$. Chose $\alpha,\beta\in H^\ast (\Sigma X;R)$ in positive degrees, where $R$ is a commutative ring with unit. How can I calculate the cup product $\alpha\cup\beta$?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Cover $\Sigma X$ with the two cones $C_+X$, $C_-X$. Use exactness and the fact that the cones are contractible to represent $\alpha$ as a class $\alpha'\in H^*(\Sigma X,C_+X)$ and represent $\beta$ as a class $\beta'\in H^*(\Sigma X,C_-X)$. Now use naturality of the relative cup product $-\cup-:H^*(\Sigma X,C_+X)\otimes H^*(\Sigma X,C_-X)\rightarrow H^*(\Sigma X, C_+X\cup C_-X)$ to get that $\alpha\cup\beta$ is the image of $\alpha'\cup\beta'\in  H^*(\Sigma X, C_+X\cup C_-X)=0$ under the natural map. It follows that $\alpha\cup\beta=0$.